# Unity3D Test Runner in PlayMode not providing test feedback

Tags: unity-game-engine, testing

I just started using Unity to build up a flappy dinosaur game. Because I am developping my game following TDD philosophy, I want to have my game tested. Therefore, here's what I tried to do without success on Unity 2019.1.9.f2:

1. Create new 2D project
2. In the TestRunner, select PlayMode
3. Create PlayMode Test Assembly Folder
4. Create Test Script in current folder

Here's the test code I want to try:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.TestTools;

namespace Tests
{
  public class NewTestScript
  {
    // A Test behaves as an ordinary method
    [Test]
    public void NewTestScriptSimplePasses()
    {
      // Use the Assert class to test conditions
      Assert.Inconclusive();
    }

    // A UnityTest behaves like a coroutine in Play Mode. In Edit Mode you can use
    // `yield return null;` to skip a frame.
    [UnityTest]
    public IEnumerator NewTestScriptWithEnumeratorPasses()
    {
      // Use the Assert class to test conditions.
      // Use yield to skip a frame.
      yield return null;
      Assert.Inconclusive();
    }
  }
}
```

The TestRunner does not provide me with any kind of feedback on the tests, except that they "didn't run" (number of green tests = number of failed tests = 0, number of not run tests = 2). I tried to restart Unity and run the tests again without any success.

That lack of feedback is interesting because if I set a breakpoint in both of those tests, then they're hit, i.e. the tests are run.

Same with 2018.4.3f1 and 2019.2.0b9.

Now if I reproduce that very experiment with Unity 2018.1.9f2, then

- `NewTestScriptSimplePasses` provides no feedback at all
- `NewTestScriptWithEnumeratorPasses` triggers an "InconclusiveException" in the console

If I replace the `Assert.Inconclusive()` with `Assert.IsTrue(false)`, then I get proper feedback in the 2nd test. If I call `Assert.IsTrue(true)` in the 2nd test, then I get no feedback. In all cases (also those where I get an exception), the green / red ticks are not shown at all on the test runner.

What am I doing wrong? In EditorMode, everything is fine.

Thanks in advance for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ... I was finally able to make it work. It might be in my opinion a bug in Unity, but I can't say with confidence as I am a very inexperienced user of Unity. Here's how I was able to get the green / red ticks: by total coincidence, I pressed the play button (to play the game, so nothing to do with the tests), and then pressed pause, then pressed pause again, then pressed the Step button. At the same time, in the version 2018.4.3f1, I was able to run the PlayMode tests. Then, suddenly the green / red ticks appeared. Since then, I don't need to run my game in play mode any more to get feedback on my tests ... it's a bit strange. Also, inconclusive assertions are not tracked correctly: there are considered passing, they should be considered the same way they are in EditorMode: inconclusive, orange circles.